# How to secure a folder location with Basic Authentication on an Nginx server

Tags: nginx, basic-authentication

Here’s a weird one.  I have a nginx server running on an Amazon EC2 instance serving static content and some services, but there is a section of the statically served content I’d like to put behind Basic Authentication.

Seems simple enough, following examples I’ve looked at [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication#restricting_access_with_nginx_and_basic_authentication),
[here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-basic-http-authentication-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04),
and [here](https://privatedock.wordpress.com/2013/12/02/set-up-http-authentication-with-nginx-on-amazon-linux/),
but what I find is that I can’t seem to get it to recognize my user/password if I try to secure a folder location and not the full site.

- this works fine to put the whole site behind Basic Auth, but I don’t want that
- If I put the auth_basic and auth_basic_user_file directives under a `location / { }` block (thereby securing the whole site) I am prompted when I access the site, as expected, and it accepts my login.
- however if I give the path to the directory I want protected, as in `location /private {…}` the password prompt comes up when I access that folder, but it fails to recognize any of my username/passwords I have registered,  so everything there is always locked out.
- The path and permissions on my password file are fine (`root:root 644`, like other configs) (if they weren’t it wouldn’t work in the `/` case, for one thing)

What am I missing?

Comment: As always, share what you tried. Also consider checking error logs.

Comment: Re: `root:root 644`  - why are you using `root` in the first place? What user is nginx running under?

Comment: Have you tried `location private` (i.e. without the leading slash)? What about a trailing slash? Is anything logged in nginx's logs? What _exactly_ are the HTTP Challenge response headers?